# How to transpose a collection of tuples to a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have an iterator that generates N tuples, but here I'll pretend I have 3. They are all even in length.

```
t1 = (a1, b1, c1)
t2 = (a2, b2, c2)
t3 = (a3, b3, c3)
```

I'm looking to convert the above into this:

```
d = {a1: [a2, a3], 
      b1: [b2, b3],
      c1: [c2, c3]}
```

I get that I should iterate over the tuples and somehow zip them into a dictionary, but I'm pretty much stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming first elements in your lists are different, you can use list comprehensions to generate the resulting dict.

Keep in mind that, all keys in a `dict` are **unique**. So if `a1` is equal to `a2`, `t1` will be overridden by `t2`.

```
>>> lists = [['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']]

>>> d = {list[0]:list[1:] for list in zip(*lists)}

>>> print d
>>> {'a1': ('a2', 'a3'), 'b1': ('b2', 'b3'), 'c1': ('c2', 'c3')}
```

Comment: Great example of using list (dict) comprehensions!

Comment: But this is not what the poster is asking.

Comment: The assumption is correct. The first elements in the list are different. This works fine for what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to accomplish what you want:

```
ls = [['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']]
# I create an iterator since that what you have in your problem
it = iter(ls)

keys = it.next()
d = {k: [] for k in keys}
for l in it:
    for i, e in enumerate(l):
        d[keys[i]].append(e)
```

The resulting dictionary is `{'a1': ['a2', 'a3'], 'c1': ['c2', 'c3'], 'b1': ['b2', 'b3']}`.

Comment: To populate `d`, you can do the following: `d = collections.defaultdict(list)`